# How to add custom admin panel in node js to modify JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, admin

I'm trying to build a listing website where iam going list job post. How do I build admin panel to edit,add,delete jobs. Iam using array inside json to store my job title and job tag
Inside json

```json
{
  "Jobs":[
    {
      "job-title":"react js",
      "Location":" newyork"
    },
    {
      "job-title":"node js",
      "Location":" newrk"
    },
    {
      "job-title":"js",
      "Location":" wyork"
    }
  }
```

How do I build custom admin in node js that will read and edit jobs array inside json.

Comment: Try to build something instead of asking us to perform CRUD. We can help you if you're getting any issues with the code, but we can't do code for you. Please post something meaningful.

Comment: IAM not asking you to do crud. I can do that. What IAM asking is how do I have admin route to show me JSON data . How can I build my own admin panel to perform crud. How do I secure admin route without having any database.

Comment: use Google! instead of StackOverflow!